# How to create and destroy component data with VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Modal component in Vue.

This Modal component has a few form fields in it:

```
<template>
    <div :class="visible">
        <input type="text" v-model="form.name">
        <input type="text" v-model="form.email">
        <input type="text" v-model="form.pass">
        <button @click="sendForm">Submit</button>
        <button @click="closeModal">Close</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                visible: false,
                form: {
                    name: '',
                    email: '',
                    pass: ''
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            sendForm() {
                // Send form
            },
            showModal() {
                this.visible = true
            },
            closeModal() {
                this.visible = false
           }
        },
    }
</script>
```

When the modal becomes visible, I am showing the form fields to the user. Let's say the user fills out the form fields but does not click on Submit. Instead, he closes the modal.

In the case, I want to `reset` the modal completely to its original form. Basically destroy the component. Then re-initialize it when the user clicks on the button to make it visible.

When the modal becomes visible again, the component should be a new instance and all the `component data` should be clear.

**What I tried:** I tried to clear the form values in the component on close. However, with more complicated forms/components it could become hard to reset each and every data property to their original state.

How can I destroy the component and re-create it? Are there any best practices for this situation?

Comment: You can pass form data as a single object as a param of showModal and then just `this.form = Object.assign({}, passedFormData)`. In `sendForm` you can emit an event with filled `this.form` object `this.$emit('dialogConfirmed', this.form)` and catch it where you use a dialog component

Answer (score 0):

You can create method to reset component data:

```js
reset() {
    Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data())
}
```

And call it, when you close modal.
Be carefull! It's works only on data properties.